# axios.get not working while am i searching product name

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, search, axios

backend

```
const ProductListFilter = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const productList = await productModel.find(req.query).collation({ locale: "en", strength: 2 });

    return res
      .status(201)
      .send({
        status: true,
        message: `Total ${productList.length} product found `,
        data: productList,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ status: false, message: error.message });
  }
};
```

frontend

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

const ProductListFilter = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch({ ...search, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/ProductListFilter`)
      .then((res) => alert(res.data.message))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.response.data.message));
  };
  console.log(search);
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="search">
          <input type="search" name="search" id="search" onChange={handleChange} />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductListFilter;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add name in query param as shown below.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

const ProductListFilter = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch({ ...search, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/ProductListFilter?name=${search.name}`)
      .then((res) => alert(res.data.message))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.response.data.message));
  };
  console.log(search);
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="search">
          <input type="search" name="search" id="search" onChange={handleChange} />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductListFilter;
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. for replying but it is also not working